# My mouse is becoming locked for a few seconds

Tags: windows-7, windows

Using Windows 7, my mouse locks up several times per hour for about three seconds. Then I hear an error sound and it frees itself.

This has been happening for three weeks. I have checked the error logs and there's nothing in them that points to this.

Has anyone experienced this? What is wrong?

Comment: Do you have a wireless mouse? If so, the batteries should be replaced.

Comment: I don't use wireless keyboards or mice. I used to and learned my lesson that not everything should be wireless.

Comment: What do you mean by "I have checked the error logs"? Event Viewer (`evtview.exe`)?

Comment: Yes, event viewer.

Comment: Use the task manager or resource monitor, it is likely that it is  another program is clogging up the cpu or bus then failing, a program leaking, a service failing and restarting (because services can be set to restart easier than programs) . It also does sound much like a crappy malware program which might show up cloning itself, or existing in the temps or other things they commonly do.

Answer (score 2):

There are several things you should do:

- First of all, check your mouse cable, try it on another computer, and
  try another mouse on your computer. Does the problem still exist?
- When it repeats, remember the exact time and check the [Event Viewer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-information-event-logs-event-viewer) logs. Is there an event/error which occured at that time? If yes, post it here. For opening the Event Viewer, do this: press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type `eventvwr`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- There is a type of malware which blocks the mouse cursor for a few seconds, sends a certain pre-programmed malicious mouse input, and then unlocks the user mouse input again. Consider scanning your computer for viruses with a reputable antivirus. Also, check your autoruns and services (Sysinternal's [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) is here to help you), and remove odd/suspicious things from the Windows startup.